# Magento 2 REST web Api related question for associate certification

Tags: magento2

1. A module MyModule needs to send notifications to customers only when the account was modified from a mobile app using the REST web APIs. You decided to implement an observer for the customer_save_after_data_object event. In which file do you declare the observer?

A. etc/webapi_rest/events.xml

B. etc/adminhtml/events.xml

C. etc/webapi/rest_events.xml

D. etc/events.xml

Answer (score 0):

well the correct ans is **D** `etc/events.xml`